# Flash/Javascript communication error

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm using the following code. It works fine with getElementByID but if I use a OS detection function it stops working.

```
function getFlashMovie(movieName) 
{
    var isIE = navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1;
    return (isIE) ? window[movieName] : document[movieName];
}

getFlashMovie('myId').sendToActionsript(str);
```

The above code does not work whereas the line below is working any Ideas?

```
document.getElementById('myId').sendToActionscript(str);
```

EDIT: Another piece of code for the same thing, which isn't working either.

```
        function getFlashMovieSecond(movieName)
        {
                    if (window.document[movieName])
                    {
                        return window.document[movieName];
                    }
                    if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet")==-1)
                    {
                        if (document.embeds && document.embeds[movieName])
                            return document.embeds[movieName];
                    }
                    else // if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet")!=-1)
                    {
                        return document.getElementById(movieName);
                    }

        }
```

Comment: Try using the example that comes with Help(http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#includeExamplesSummary) - gradually strip off the bits that you don't need and incorporate the code into your project. A think to keep in mind is that some browsers get Flash content using the embed tag, while others use the object tag, so make sure you've got the same name/id on both tags, and also that AllowScriptAccess it set to "always". HTH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work

```
 function thisMovie(movieName) {

    if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {

                    return window[movieName];

    } else {

                    return document[movieName];

    }
```

}